# Pergunta feita em outro idioma traduzido na edição, o que fazer?

Tags: suporte, edições-sugeridas, filas-de-análise, idioma

Vi na fila de análise uma pergunta feita toda em inglês pelo autor, e na sugestão de edição o outro usuário traduziu a questão.

Qual ação devo tomar na fila de análise, devo aprovar esse tipo de edição caso seja uma tradução válida, ou rejeitar considerando que deva ser uma responsabilidade do próprio usuário que fez a pergunta traduzi-lá para evitar possíveis distorções do entendimento da pergunta?

Comment: Se você estiver certo de que foi uma boa tradução aprove, se tem certeza que esta ruim rejeite ou "rejeite e edite". Se você não tem um bom inglês simplesmente pule a questão (botão "pular/skip").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sim, as perguntas precisam estar em português. Se ficar em inglês, será fechada e possivelmente removida. Se o próprio autor não traduziu e alguém da comunidade resolveu ajudar, ótimo! A menos, é claro, que a tradução esteja muito ruim e/ou deturpe a intenção do autor.

Comment: Entendido, fiquei na dúvida pois pensei que isso poderia ser responsabilidade do próprio autor justamente por poder distorcer a intenção do autor.

Comment: A responsabilidade é mesmo do autor, mas o sistema não impede que outros o ajudem - o que é positivo.